# How to run a C++ program in personal software without rebuild

Tags: c++, visual-c++, arduino, simulation

I have a project that need to simulate Arduino. I can simulate Arduino base on Its libraries (like this: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=132710.0), in this way arduino program is a part of project and is compiled when build project. But, my project request is higher, that is the software can be load a new Arduino program (like a C++ program).

So in my software, Is there any way that I can load new arduino program without rebuild all project?

Thank for your attention.

Comment: What are the issues with rebuilding all the project?

Comment: When I release my software to customer, they can't use Visual Studio to rebuild whole project if they want to change their Arduino program.

Answer (score 0):

You dont want to recompile or  rebuild exe .You can replace the old /bin, /data and /lib of arduino with the new release version of arduino. In that way, new version of arduino can be loaded. Make sure your calling function's signature are same to library else you need to get their exported header files to rebuild your exe.